# SQL Server authentication for a Database file

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I use Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2013. I created `Database1.mdf` in my `App_Data` folder. By default, it uses integrated Windows authentication. I have no problem connect to this database file, but when I update all file into web space and browse it in browser, it has an error. I think I need to change it to SQL Server authentication instead of integrated Windows authentication.

My questions are:

1. How can I change it to SQL Server authentication step by step? I want to connect this data file with user name & password.
2. How to assign user into it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to attach the database file to your SQL Server:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhIr9Qf-oHw

Then you create the type of logins you want:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uh5USR7pymE

You can now detach the database. Your application can use now the new logins. If you change from Windows to User/password your connection will need to say so, something like:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

I also found this helpful link that describes also the steps:

[SQLExpress - How do I set username/password for a sql datafile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624655/sqlexpress-how-do-i-set-username-password-for-a-sql-datafile)

Hope this helps.

Comment: If the link for "SQLExpress - How do I set username/password for a sql datafile" helps you please remember to thank @Gabriel as well.